# How to print and edit variable content at the same place on runtime of a Unix shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I have been looking all around (with no avail) to perform the following:

I want to display and able to edit if necessary the content of a variable in runtime for a Unix shell script after giving it a value. The idea goes like this:

Suppose we have a variable value either defined in script or by user input

```
var=12345
```

Print the variable value, but also leave the cursor in that position of printing and either press just enter to leave it intact or enter a new value in runtime

Edit variable content (press Enter to leave intact) : **1**2345

at this point at runtime, I want to leave the cursor in the position of number 1, while showing the variable, and working in the way that if I press Enter, leave the original content (12345) or read for a new value in that same place and modify. Clearing the display of the variable when typing anything else than Enter would be a big plus.

I have looked all around for a way to do this, but just haven't found anything. Anyone willing to provide a solution?

Comment: The problem is redirecting the cursor to that place and keeping that value by just pressing Enter. All the sample code I've tried is very obscure, so what I try just gives me error, that's why I ventured to ask in here. Something like: echo -n 12345; echo -e "\r56" -OR- echo "12345"; printf '\r67\n' of course 12345 comes from a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you doing this in another way:

```
var=12345
echo "Change the value of Var (current value: $var)"
read -p "New value (Press Enter to skip):" nvar
if [[ "$nvar" != "" ]]; then
    var="$nvar"
fi
echo $var
```

with this, it will prompt:

```
Change the value of Var (current value: 12345)
New value (Press Enter to skip):
```

what you wanted in the question (**without** the "big plus" part), could be achieved too:

```
var=12345
echo -ne "Now you may want to change the value: \n$var\r"
read nvar
if [[ "$nvar" != "" ]]; then
    var="$nvar"
fi
echo $var
```

with this, it will prompt (cursor sits between `**` )

```
Now you may want to change the value: 
*1*2345
```

Comment: Let me try it out and report back! Thanks KENT!

Comment: This method works, it would be nice that when the user inputs any other character, then the old variable characters dissapear...

Comment: by the way, how do you place the read of nvar next to the print of the message of the echo? code places nvar in a new line

Comment: for your 1st comment, I mentioned in my answer (**without the big plus part**) . for your 2nd comment, I don't understand....

Answer (score 0):

With bash, you could use the readline option for `read`, but that does not put the cursor at the beginning. It does however do what you want

```
var=12345
read -ep "Enter new value: " -i $var var
```

If you need the cursor to go back, you can do this:

```
var=12345
prompt="Enter new value: $var"
for ((i=1; i<=${#var}; i++)); do prompt+=$'\b'; done
read -p "$prompt" new
[[ -z $new ]] && new=$var
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your code... for loop goes back per each character of $var with /b right? Is [[ -z $new ]] a simplified test command? Also I'm not really sure what is happening with the read command with option -p ... can you please explain? Thanks in advance

Comment: The `-p` option provides the text for the prompt. See `help read` at a bash command line. This `[[ ... ]] && ...` is a shorthand for `if [[ ... ]]; then ...; fi`. You are correct about the for loop: `\b` is a backspace character (in the same way that `\n` is a newline)